# No suitable driver found for mysql (Remote debugging)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi i have found a seemingly common problem, i cant interact with a mysql db. This no suitable driver  found keeps happening.
I have followed most threads on this same question, however i was not able to replicate their solution so am posting my own specific question.

(Mostly this thread: [I can't load the JDBC driver for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164950/i-cant-load-the-jdbc-driver-for-mysql))

My code:

```
public DBManager(){
    try {
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver()); 

        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:3306//localhost/test","root","root");
        //con=DriverManager.getConnection(c);
        if(!con.isClosed()) {
            con.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now,  i read that on newer drivers you dont need either Class.forName () or registerDriver();
i have tried both and i still cant get it to work.

The thing is am developing on a windows machine, with eclipse Indigo and Connector/J 5.1.17

and deploying (and debugging) on a remote linux with the same Connector.

Am launching my debug sessions with

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y  -classpath /home/dev/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar -jar devserver.jar

and i get that exception. Any help?

I come from a heavy c# development environment, so if i have to meddle with classpaths and such please try to step it by step as im not very familiar with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SQLException: no suitable driver

You will get this exception whenever the [`DriverManager#getConnection()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties%29) cannot find a suitable driver for the given connection URL. This in turn happens when the [`Driver#acceptsURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#acceptsURL%28java.lang.String%29) has returned `false` for any of the loaded drivers.

And indeed, your connection URL is wrong:

```
jdbc:mysql:3306//localhost/test
```

It should have been:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

See also the [MySQL JDBC manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host:port],[host:port].../[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> If the database is not specified, the connection will be made with no default database.

Comment: thats what happens when you look too much at the same code. you miss the obvious. cant believe i did that