# No suitable driver found for jdbc:presto

Tags: maven, jdbc, presto

I want to connect Presto DB by JDBC.

```
 String sql="Select * from mysql.infsci2711toturial.Person";
 String url="jdbc:presto://localhost:8080/catalog";//Under catalog folder, there is my mysql.properties file.

 Connection connection=null;
 try{
     connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", null);
     Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
     while(rs.next()){
         System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
     }
 }catch(SQLException ex){
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs()));
     ex.printStackTrace();

     System.out.println("wrong connection!");
 }
```

The problem show in eclipse is that: 
        **No suitable driver found for jdbc:presto://localhost:8080/catalog**
I have tried to put presto-jdbc-0.93.jar under WEB-INF/lib. But don't solve this problem. How to solve this problem. Do I need set Maven? and how?

Comment: I think you're missing the driver load within your application runtime. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6164950/3127111) for a code example, as I have none to show you. You basically need to call `Class.forName()` passing the driver name (it should be available in the docs).

Comment: Thanks, it solves half of problem!

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_presto/apache_presto_jdbc_interface.htm

Answer (score 2):

Add "Class.forName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");"
And presto require JDK 1.8. So update JRE to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem consists of two parts:

1- Finding the right connetor.
2- Finding the right connection url.

In my case, I needed to connect to Presto on AWS EMR and the following worked for me:

- Include presto-jdbc driver in your maven dependancies

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.presto/presto-jdbc -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
      <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>0.198</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Include the driver class in your classpath:

  `final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver";
  Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);`
- Use the right connection url:

  `final String DB_URL = "jdbc:presto://Your_ec2_ip_address:8889/hive/default";`
- Make sure that the port **8889** is open on the server
- `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "hadoop", "");`

Hope this helps.